# In Cosmos DB, how to detect and react to document size before I create it

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to manage my documents around the 2mb size limit.
What is the most efficient, accurate, and least resource intensive way to get the size of the document before you try to create it?

Answer (score 1):

You can serialise the object you are about to add in CosmosDB and then get the length of the string in bytes.

Keep in mind this won't be 100% accurate because cosmos will add all it's own metadata properties like `etag` etc, but it is close enough.

Worth saying that i personally don't recommend this approach but it is probably the closest thing you can get if you want to get the size before even adding it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible before creating, anyhow , Look at the headers that come back when you query a document specifically x-ms-resource-usage, which will contain a **`documentsSize`** attribute

```
client.readDocument(doc, function (err, doc, headers) {
  ...
})
```

Comment: I found this, but I'm not sure it's working correctly:

                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(series);
                var sizeMethod1 = json.Length * sizeof(Char);
                var sizeMethod2 = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json).Length;
                log.Info($"Document Size Method 1: {sizeMethod1} and Size Method 2: {sizeMethod2}");

Comment: That is an ugly comment.  Hope it makes some sense.

Comment: no this will return a different value, you should actually store and query it.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Sounds like he wants to know the size of it before it is even added.

Comment: @NickChapsas thats what i have mentioned in the comment too